# SML - Error: types of if branches do not agree

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to code an SML function that returns an array of results in listViolations(L1, L2). I specifically want to cross reference each element with eachother O(n^2), and check to see if the selection conflicts with one another. To visualize: [[1, 2], [2, 3]] is option 1 and [[3, 2], [2, 1]] is option two. I would call listViolations like this: listViolations([[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[3, 2], [2, 1]]]).

The plan of action would be to :

```
fun listViolations(L1, L2) =
    if L1 = [] orelse L2 = []
        then 0
     else totalViolations(transitive_closure(hd(L1)),path(hd(L2)))::[] @ listViolations(L1, tl(L2))::[] @ listViolations(tl(L1), L2)::[];
```

Here I am checking the head of both lists, and passing on the tails of both recursively, in hopes of creating something like this: [3, 0 , 0].

Although I am getting this error when I declare the function:

```
stdIn:726.5-728.136 Error: types of if branches do not agree [overload conflict]
then branch: [int ty]
else branch: int list
in expression:
  if (L1 = nil) orelse (L2 = nil)
  then 0
  else totalViolations (transitive_closure <exp>,path <exp>) ::
       nil @ listViolations <exp> :: <exp> @ <exp>
```

I provided all my other functions below to show that there's nothing wrong with them, I just want to know if there's something im doing wrong. I know for a fact that

- totalViolations(transitive_closure(hd(L1)),path(hd(L2)))
- listViolations(L1, tl(L2))::[]
- listViolations(tl(L1), L2)::[];

return integers. How do I make a list out of it and return it within this function? Thank you in advance.

```
//[1, 2] , [1, 2, 3] = 0
//[3, 2] , [1, 2, 3] = 1
fun violation(T, P) =
    if indexOf(hd(T), P) < indexOf(hd(tl(T)), P)  then 0
    else 1;

//[[1, 2], [2, 3]] , [1, 2, 3] = 0
//[[3, 2], [2, 1]] , [1, 2, 3] = 2
fun totalViolations(TS, P) =
    if TS = [] then 0
    else violation(hd(TS), P) + totalViolations(tl(TS), P);

//[[1, 2],[2, 3]] -> [1, 2, 3]
fun path(L) =
    if L = [] orelse L =[[]]
        then []
    else union(hd(L),path(tl(L)));

// [[1, 2],[2, 3]] -> [[1, 2],[2, 3], [1, 3]]
fun transitive_closure(L) = union(L, remove([], closure(L, L)));
```

Additional Code:

```
fun len(L) = if (L=nil) then 0 else 1+length(tl(L));

fun remove(x, L) =
    if L = [] then []
    else if x = hd(L) then remove(x, tl(L))
    else hd(L)::remove(x, tl(L));

fun transitive(L1, L2) =
    if len(L1) = 2 andalso len(L2) = 2 andalso tl(L1) = hd(L2)::[]
        then hd(L1)::tl(L2)
    else [];

fun closure(L1, L2) =
    if (L1 = [[]] orelse L2 = [[]] orelse L1 = [] orelse L2 = [])
        then [[]]
    else if len(L1) = 1 andalso len(L2) = 1
        then transitive(hd(L1), hd(L2))::[]
    else
        union( union(closure(tl(L1), L2), closure(L1, tl(L2))), transitive(hd(L1), hd(L2))::[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `then` branch of your `if` is an `int` while the `else` branch is a list of ints. To form a list in the former, write `[0]` (which is just short for `0::[]`). Also, the result of the recursive calls in the other branch is already expected to return a list, so the consing with `[]` is wrong, because it forms a list of lists.

More tips: *never* compare to the empty list, that will force the element type to be an equality type. Use the `null` predicate instead. Even better (and much more readable), avoid `null`, `hd`, and `tail` altogether and use pattern matching.

Comment: - fun listViolations(L1, L2) =
=     if L1 = [] orelse L2 = []
=         then [0]
=     else totalViolations(transitive_closure(hd(L1)),path(hd(L2)))::[] @ listViolations(L1, tl(L2))::[] @ listViolations(tl(L1), L2)::[]
stdIn:649.2-734.136 Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [tycon mismatch]
  expression:  int list
  result type:  int
  in declaration:
    listViolations =
      (fn (L1,L2) =>
            if <exp> orelse <exp> then <exp> :: <exp> else <exp> :: <exp>)     What would I need to get the desired output, a list of ints?

Comment: Remove the `::[]` after the two recursive calls.

Comment: Im sorry, I tired and Im still getting errors. Can you please show me the code for the working version?